# Making custom column in laravel Datatables depends on another column

Tags: laravel, datatable

I have a column `type` in my database. The `type` values are **Debit** & **Credit**. There is also a column `net_total`. I am using laravel datatables to show the data. Now I want to make 2 fixed column name `Debit` and `Credit` in the datatable where the `net_total` for **debit** will be in the debit column in  datatable and the process will be the same for **credit** also.

This is how I'm fetching data from database:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.net_total , a.date, a.type, a.reference_number, a.account_name, a.uuid
                FROM accounts AS a";

if ($request->ajax()) {
                return DataTables::of(DB::select($query))->addIndexColumn()
                        ->editColumn('reference_number', function ($row) {
                            return  $row->reference_number;
                        })
                        ->rawColumns(['reference_number'])->make(true);
}
            return view('accountManager.report.summary');
```

This is the blade view

```
<div id="datatable" class="mb-5">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <table id="laravel_datatable" class="table text-nowrap w-100">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>{{'SL'}}</th>
                                            <th>{{'Date'}}</th>
                                            <th>{{'Account Name'}}</th>
                                            <th>{{'Reference Number'}}</th>
                                            <th>{{'Type'}}</th>
                                            <th>{{'Amount'}}</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <x-card-border></x-card-border>
                            </div>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            load_data();
            function addCommas(nStr)
            {
                nStr += '';
                x = nStr.split('.');
                x1 = x[0];
                x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
                var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
                while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
                }
                return x1 + x2;
            }
            function load_data(from_date = '', to_date = '') {
                $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
                    
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    lengthMenu: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                    responsive: true,
                    dom: "<'row mb-3'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8 text-end'<'d-flex justify-content-end'fB>>>t<'d-flex align-items-center'<'me-auto'i><'mb-0'p>>",
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-secondary buttons-print btn-outline-default btn-sm ms-2',

                            customize: function ( win ) {
                                $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                                    .addClass( 'compact' )
                                    .css( 'color', '#020202' );
                            },
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: [0, 1, 2,3,4, "visible"]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'csv', className: 'btn btn-secondary buttons-csv buttons-html5 btn-outline-default btn-sm'
                        }
                    ],
                    ajax: {
                        url: '{{ route("report.summary") }}',
                        data: {from_date: from_date, to_date: to_date}
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                        {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
                        {data: 'account_name', name: 'account_name'},
                        {data: 'reference_number', name: 'reference_number'},
                        {data: 'type', name: 'type'},
                        {data: 'net_total', name: 'net_total'}
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your question, but it sounds like you can use a DataTables [column render](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) function. The `function (data, type, row) { ... }` gives you access to all the values in each row (using the `row` variable). You can create one renderer for `debit` and one for `credit`. No need to change the database table definition.

Comment: There are [many stack overflow questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=datatables+column+render+site:stackoverflow.com) covering this with more examples.

Answer (score 0):

use [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) (give you mysql version but it mostly the same in other databases)

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       (case
            when a.type = 'Debit' then a.debit
            when a.type = 'Credit' then a.credit
           end
       ) as net_total,
       a.date,
       a.type,
       a.reference_number,
       a.account_name,
       a.uuid
FROM accounts AS a;
```

Comment: It says, Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.debit' in 'field list' (SQL: SELECT a.id, (case when a.type = 'DEBIT' then a.debit when a.type = 'CREDIT' then a.credit end ) as net_total, a.date, a.type, a.reference_number, a.account_name, a.uuid FROM accounts AS a;)

Comment: @DebjitPaul you said >Now I want to make 2 fixed column name Debit and Credit in the datatable - add columns to the table before execute code

Answer (score 0):

as far as I get you request you can use below code for creating 2 fix column based what you want
in controller change to this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.net_total , a.date, a.type, a.reference_number, a.account_name, a.uuid
            FROM accounts AS a";

if ($request->ajax()) {
            return DataTables::of(DB::select($query))->addIndexColumn()
                    ->editColumn('reference_number', function ($row) {
                        return  $row->reference_number;
                    })
                    ->addColumn('Debit', function ($query) {
                       if($order->type == 'Debit'){
                          return $query->net_total;
                       }  
                    })
                    ->addColumn('Credit', function ($query) {
                       if($order->type == 'Credit'){
                          return $query->net_total;
                       }  
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['reference_number','Debit','Credit'])->make(true);}
return view('accountManager.report.summary');
```

and then change blade view to this :

```
<div id="datatable" class="mb-5">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table id="laravel_datatable" class="table text-nowrap w-100">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>{{'SL'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Date'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Account Name'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Reference Number'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Type'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Debit'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Credit'}}</th>
                                        <th>{{'Amount'}}</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <x-card-border></x-card-border>
                        </div>
</div>
```

and finaly you script to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        load_data();
        function addCommas(nStr)
        {
            nStr += '';
            x = nStr.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }
            return x1 + x2;
        }
        function load_data(from_date = '', to_date = '') {
            $('#laravel_datatable').DataTable({
                
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                lengthMenu: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
                responsive: true,
                dom: "<'row mb-3'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8 text-end'<'d-flex justify-content-end'fB>>>t<'d-flex align-items-center'<'me-auto'i><'mb-0'p>>",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'print', className: 'btn btn-secondary buttons-print btn-outline-default btn-sm ms-2',

                        customize: function ( win ) {
                            $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                                .addClass( 'compact' )
                                .css( 'color', '#020202' );
                        },
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, 1, 2,3,4, "visible"]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        extend: 'csv', className: 'btn btn-secondary buttons-csv buttons-html5 btn-outline-default btn-sm'
                    }
                ],
                ajax: {
                    url: '{{ route("report.summary") }}',
                    data: {from_date: from_date, to_date: to_date}
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                    {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
                    {data: 'account_name', name: 'account_name'},
                    {data: 'reference_number', name: 'reference_number'},
                    {data: 'type', name: 'type'},
                    {data: 'Debit', name: 'net_total'},
                    {data: 'Credit', name: 'net_total'},
                    {data: 'net_total', name: 'net_total'}
                ]
            });
        }
    });
```